# Recording when car is detected

Tags: python, camera, artificial-intelligence, python-tesseract, opencv

I'm working on a AI project for Car License Plate Detection and I need some help.

I want to record a video for 10 sec only when the car is detected.

The above code records the video even when it's not detecting a car.

How can I change the code so it works?

In addition, I want to source from 8 different cameras/frames so they will be displayed first and recorded simultaneously for 10 sec each camera when they detect a car.

From the recording I want to crop an image with the Car License Plate recognition and save it in the computer as png/jpg file

```
import cv2
import datetime
import pytesseract

# Load the pre-trained car detection model
car_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_car.xml')

# Initialize variables for recording
is_recording = False
start_time = None
record_duration = datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
recorded_frames = {}
car_index = 1

# Open the video capture device (default camera)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Check if the camera was successfully opened
if not cam.isOpened():
    print("Failed to open the camera.")
    exit(1)

while True:
    # Read a frame from the camera
    ret, frame = cam.read()

    # Break the loop if no frame is captured
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert the frame to grayscale for car detection
    gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect cars in the frame
    cars = car_detector.detectMultiScale(gray_frame, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(50, 50))

    # Draw rectangles around the detected cars
    for (x, y, w, h) in cars:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        # Start recording when a car is detected
        if not is_recording:
            is_recording = True
            start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            recorded_frames[car_index] = []

    # Record frames if a car is detected
    if is_recording:
        recorded_frames[car_index].append(frame)

        # Stop recording if there are no car detections for 10 seconds
        if datetime.datetime.now() - start_time >= record_duration and len(cars) == 0:
            is_recording = False
            # Save the recorded frames as a video file
            if len(recorded_frames[car_index]) > 0:
                output_path = f"car_{car_index}.avi"
                car_index += 1
                output_width = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
                output_height = int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
                output_fps = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

                writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID"), output_fps, (output_width, output_height))
                for recorded_frame in recorded_frames[car_index - 1]:
                    writer.write(recorded_frame)
                writer.release()

                # Save a picture of the license plate from the last recorded frame
                last_frame_with_plate = recorded_frames[car_index - 1][-1]
                license_plate_frame = last_frame_with_plate[y:y + h, x:x + w]
                cv2.imwrite(f"plate_{car_index - 1}.jpg", license_plate_frame)

                # Perform OCR on the license plate frame to recognize the plate number
                license_plate_number = pytesseract.image_to_string(license_plate_frame)
                print("Detected license plate number:", license_plate_number)

                # Reset recording variables
                start_time = None

    # Break the loop if 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture object and close all windows
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Almost everything, different libraries, tutorials on youtube and so on.